# Tracking a Facebook comment

Tags: facebook, links

After posting a comment on a Facebook page, it gets buried under hundreds of other comments. How can I find that specific comment and share that information with my friends. I want to get 'likes' for my comment. But no one can find it. I cannot right click on it to get a URL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Just right click on the time when the comment has been added and copy the link.

[image]

[Pasted link](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151440273408553&set=a.441861428552.204523.19292868552&type=1&comment_id=9050999&offset=0&total_comments=54)

This link will redirect to this specific comment and the background will fade from yellow to blue for a second.